# Союз "и" в сложной фразе

Tags: союзы, многозначность

Во фразе

> О совершенствовании регулирования отдельных вопросов организации и
> функционирования публичной власти

союз "и" соединяет
"отдельных вопросов организации" и "функционирования"
или же
"регулирования отдельных вопросов организации" и "функционирования" ?

Т.е. мы совершенствуем некое регулирование, которое регулирует вопросы и функционирование?
Или же мы совершенствуем и регулирование вопросов, и функционирование?

Возможно ли устранить многозначность в этой фразе, и если да, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Союз попросту соединяет здесь слова "организация" и "функционирование", употребленные в родительном падеже. Смысл носителем языка воспринимается однозначно: вопросы *организации и функционирования* власти хотят регулировать более совершенным образом - что бы это ни означало. Поиск других смыслов представляется здесь надуманным и наводит на мысль о попытках юридической экспертизы написанного.

Comment: Спасибо!

Совершенствовать, думаю, можно как регулирование так и функционирование, не так ли?

А если можно совершенствовать, то можно и регулировать.


Не могли бы вы объяснить, чем руководствовались при выборе грамматических основ, которые соединяет союз "и"?


На данном этапе я ищу один единственный смысл : )
Для подтверждения этого, можете провести эксперимент и спросить у своих друзей, не профессиональных юристов, филологов и лингвистов - что соединяет союз "и" в этом предложении.

Comment: Видимо, читающий непроизвольно начинает осмысление с ближайших к союзу слов, а потом уже (если не найдет таковых) начинает искать усложненные конструкции, которые могут располагаться удаленно. В нашем случае соединяемые существительные сопадают по падежу, поэтому не возникает потребности перечитать текст и поискать другие смыслы.